# AJAX function on permanent error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Something is wrong with this AJAX function but I do not see what.

AJAX

```
$('.review').click(function() {
    var idatas = $(this).attr('rel');
    var idata = 'idata=' + idatas;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo $thisposturl;?>?review',
        data: idata,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(this).addClass('ractive');
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#dbody').html(data.ioutput);

            $('.cright').height($('#dropout').height());
            $('#dropout').addClass('dropopen');
        },
        error: function(data) {
             $('#dbody').html('arse biscuity');
             $('.cright').height($('#dropout').height());
             $('#dropout').addClass('dropopen');
        }
    });
```

PHP

```
<?php 

$rid = $_POST['idata'];

$ireviews = get_posts('post_type=reviews&p='.$rid.'&numberposts=-1');

foreach ($ireviews as $ireview) :   
setup_postdata($post);

$ioutput = '<div class="iavatar"></div>
<div class="ititle">'.get_the_title($ireview).'<br />
<div class="iauthor">'.get_the_author($ireview).'</div></div>
<div class="icontent">'.get_the_content($ireview).'</div>';

endforeach;
echo json_encode(array('ioutput'=> $ioutput));


?>
```

According to Firebug the response is this

```
{"ioutput":"<div class=\"iavatar\"><\/div>\n<div class=\"ititle\">What a lovely course<br \/>\n<div class=\"iauthor\">pm master<\/div><\/div>\n<div class=\"icontent\">This intimate layout, with its undulating and springy fairways that zigzag in amongst the woodland setting, calls for accurate driving and precision shot-making into the well-bunkered greens; another classic Colt trademark. Position, not power, is the name of the game here.<\/div>"}
```

But it is going to error function and not putting the content in `#dbody`

Any ideas?

Comment: What response code is being received?

Comment: What is the javascript error?

Comment: I don't know. But it is defaulting to the error function above

Comment: Why exactly are you using `json` for this? A simple `html` call would suffice.

Comment: Remove `?review` from the end of the URL; see if it works then.

Comment: @wanovak Cannot remove the ?review as that is what triggers the correct page where the PHP lies.  @bazmegakapa - how do I do that

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [$.ajaxSetup()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) to get the correct error like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                alert('Not connect.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                alert('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                alert('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                alert('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                alert('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                alert('Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In case of any error in the Ajax call, you will get proper alert.